# R: Using %>% to group_by(id) for correlation

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to calculate the cross-correlation between two HeartRate and roomCO2Interp for each participant (called A and B) in my experiment:

```
set.seed(395)
library(dplyr)

df2 <- data.frame(HeartRate= c(cumsum(rnorm(32*60*36,0,0.01)),
                               cumsum(rnorm(32*60*36,0,0.01))),
                  roomCO2Interp= c(cumsum(rnorm(32*60*36,0,0.01)),
                               cumsum(rnorm(32*60*36,0,0.01))),
                  ID = rep(c("A","B"), each=32*60*36))
```

[image]

I'm trying to use the pipe argument to group_by(id) but it doesn't seem to work properly:

```
crossCor<-df2 %>% group_by(id)%>%
  summarise(ccf(diff(roomCO2Interp), diff(HeartRate), type="correlation"))

Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : expecting a single value
```

Comment: What exactly do you want from the `ccf` function? By default it just seems to plot things. What value hare you opting to include in the `summarize()`?

Comment: As the error says, `summarise` is expecting a single value from your function for each group. `ccf` returns a plot or a list. You can wrap it in a `list` if you want to keep everything.

Comment: There are three other problems: (1) should be `group_by(ID)` (case); (2) you need to *assign* the return value to something, e.g., `summarize(ret = ccf(...))`; and (3) `ccf(...)` doesn't work whether grouped or not: `Error in ts(x) : 'ts' object must have one or more observations`. Once you resolve those three, you should be able to do what you want, perhaps using something like `summarize(ret = purrr::pmap(list(roomCO2Interp, HeartRate), function(a,b) ccf(diff(a), diff(b), type="correlation")))`.